# Set Different Amounts for Different Currencies in Flutterwave

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, flutterwave

Hi I am using the flutterwave api gateway to create a payment form which will have different preset amounts in different currencies. for example

USD -10

KES-100

UGX-1000

My thoughts were to put a select box and you choose the currency and then enter your details and press pay.

Would This be possible in asp.net ? Anyone done something close to this? How to pass the values to the api?

Answer (score 0):

Its Posible...
I have a working
prototype... of sorts.

I created the values in a select box and made the currency and amounts separately. Then pooled the values and passed them to the api with the preset values currency and amount. The flutterwave api gets this info and serves up the right payment method for that particular currency.

```
<form method="POST" class="payment-form-africa" action="https://checkout.flutterwave.com/v3/hosted/pay">
    <input name="customer[email]" asp-for="email" />
    <input name="customer[name]" asp-for="name"/>
    <input name="tx_ref" asp-for="tx_ref"/>
    <input name="amount" asp-for="amount"/>
    <input name="currency" asp-for="currency"/> 
 <button type="submit">Pay</button>
```

Thanks everyone.